# How do i create a "before" and "after" link on my nested episodes show page in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have my this episode model which is nested in stories and stories nested in genre... like so:

```
resources :genre do
  resources :stories do
     resources :episodes
  end
end
```

Please can someone explain how to create a "next" and "previous" button on the episode show page because i've tried to do this but did not get it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use **will_paginate** library but don't show page_links as below:

```
<%= will_paginate @episodes, :page_links => false %>
```

**Example:**
http://mislav.github.io/will_paginate/?page=2

**Source:**
https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate